# Jquery .then chain behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that returns a function with an assinged `.then` function.

```
Func = function () {
    return Func1([a, b])()
        .then(_.bind(function () {
          //something
        }, this));
  };
```

And later I assign another `.then` function to `Func`, like this:

```
Func2 = function(){
    //something
    this.Func()
        .then(_.bind(function () {
          //something
        }, this));
  };
```

Will there be a chain like `Func1().then().then()` or something else?

Comment: Yes. You can use `.then().then().then()` as multiple times as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). And on a promise you can do so much [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) as you like! ;)

```
function callback() {
    console.log("then");
}

var p = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve();
}).then(callback);

p.then(callback);
p.then(callback).then(callback);
p.then(callback).then(callback).then(callback);
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/7dhjxxhv/)**

Or as for your example:

```
var Func1 = function(param1) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        resolve();
    });
}

var Func = function() {
    return Func1(["a", "b"]).then(function() {
        console.log("then");
    }.bind(this));
};

var Func2 = function() {
    Func().then(function () {
        console.log("then");
    }.bind(this))
    .then(function() {
        console.log("then chain");
    });
};

Func2();
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/7dhjxxhv/1/)**